# MySQL Error Getting Values with Span

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have another query about my database, I'm using Codeigniter and wheneve I get the data using span and saving it to my MySQL database it inludes a \n in the data and that causes error. Why is that so? here is the problem

```
VALUES('\n16', 'SMDC')`
```

but Im onlu getting the value of 16 in my column where it is set to span.

Answer (score 0):

well \n is a special character for mysql and other languages and it means: end of line (character line). you have to escape that kind of characters using another backslash "\" before them.

See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

For you with codeigniter an example is this:

$search = '\n16';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%'";

See this for more info:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html